# Erro de conexão mysql_query

Tags: mysql, c++, string

```
#include <mysql/mysql.h>
#include <iostream>

MYSQL connection;
void data_insert();

int main(){

    mysql_init(&connection);

    if(mysql_real_connect(&connection,"localhost","root","irineuvocênãosabenemeu","teste",0,NULL,0)){
        std::cout << "Conexão com o banco de dados realizada com sucesso\n";
        data_insert();
    }else{
        std::cout << "ERRO: " << mysql_errno(&connection);
        std::cout << "\nNão foi possível realizar uma conexão com o servidor\n";
    exit(1);
    }

    return 0;
}

void data_insert(){

    std::string CPF;
    std::string nome;
    unsigned res;

    std::cout << "Insira seu CPF: ";
    getline(std::cin,CPF);
    std::cout << "Insira seu nome: ";
    getline(std::cin,nome);

    res=mysql_query(&connection,"INSERT INTO user(CPF, name) values('"+CPF+"','"+nome+"');"); //O erro está nesta linha

    if(res==0){
        std::cout << "Dados inseridos com sucesso\n";
        mysql_close(&connection);
    }else{
        system("clear");
        std::cout << "Ouve um erro ao inserir os dados, por favor tente novamente\n\n";
        main();
    }
}
```

Como faço para reverter o erro no código acima?

> error: cannot convert ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string’ to ‘const
>   char*’ for argument ‘2’ to ‘int mysql_query(MYSQL*, const char*)’|

Answer (score 0):

Você inverteu a ordem dos parâmetros.

```
res=mysql_query("INSERT INTO user(CPF, name) values('"+CPF+"','"+nome+"');", &connection);
```

Segundo a [documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysql-query.php), o *resource* vem como segundo parâmetro.

Comment: Tá faltando o caractere de terminação "

Comment: Agora deu esse error: cannot convert ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>’ to ‘MYSQL* {aka st_mysql*}’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘int mysql_query(MYSQL*, const char*)’|

Comment: Essa pergunta parece ser o mesmo ponto que você precisa: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24438636/mysql-query-string-not-working-in-query-c